How to divide the values in a single line into multiple lines, and also to remove the duplicates in xslt 3.0
Input:
<AAA>RIO_CBI_TE01_1 RIO_CBI_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 </AAA>

Question: I have to divide this into multiple lines after space, and remove duplicates
Output expected:
<AAA>RIO_CBI_TE01_1</AAA>
<AAA>RIO_ATC_TE01_1</AAA>


Use something like //AAA => tokenize() => distinct-values() to get the unique values

@Fravadona I tried this. its not working

Well, it's not a XSLT but a XPath that you can use in it. Please edit your question and add the XSLT code you wrote

You really need to say what version of XSLT. Many people are still using XSLT 1.0; but the problem is much easier to solve with later versions.

Sorry. Please use tags for the XSLT version - I didn't spot it in the title.

@Smiley, did you have a chance to try the proposed solution?

Please try the following solution.
Input XML
<AAA>RIO_CBI_TE01_1 RIO_CBI_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 RIO_ATC_TE01_1 </AAA>

XSLT
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/AAA">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(tokenize(normalize-space(.), ' '))">
                <AAA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </AAA>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<root>
  <AAA>RIO_CBI_TE01_1</AAA>
  <AAA>RIO_ATC_TE01_1</AAA>
</root>


taken from fn:tokenize's spec fn:tokenize($input) is equivalent to calling fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space($input), ' '))

@Fravadona, I tried that option too, but it was producing an empty <AAA></AAA>. That's why I added normalize-space(.) function call. I am using Saxon 9.7.0.15

If that is the case then it might be worth filling in a bug report

"filling in a bug report". Not unless you move to a later Saxon version, please. Researching exactly what version of the draft XSLT 3.0 spec was implemented in a product version released back in 2015, before XSLT 3.0 was finalised, becomes a bit of a nightmare.
